# Angular Module Organization/Architecture

Tags: angularjs

Having worked with angular for a while now, I am now seeing people break a single application out into multiple modules and I am debating the merits of such an approach.

### Single Module

```
angular.module('myApp', []);
angular.module('myApp').controller('FooCtrl', function(){});
angular.module('myApp').service('foo', function(){});
angular.module('myApp').directive('fooElement', function(){});
```

### Multiple Modules

```
angular.module('myApp.Controllers', []);
angular.module('myApp.Controllers').controller('FooCtrl', function(){});
angular.module('myApp.Services', []);
angular.module('myApp.Services').service('foo', function(){});
angular.module('myApp.Directives');
angular.module('myApp.Directives').directive('fooElement', function(){});

// Then inject the separate modules into the "parent" module
angular.module('myApp', [
    'myApp.Controllers',
    'myApp.Services',
    'myApp.Directives']);
```

I am all for modularity, but these separate modules are so specific that they are not going to get any reuse outside of the app in which they are created that they will not be re-used for any other purpose (read: not injected into any other module).

So what is the point that one would decide to separate your app which is defined as a singular module into multiple modules when reuse outside is not a valid concern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Generally speaking

The same question could be asked for any platform that has modular application development. Why seperate a .NET application into separate assemblies if all of the code is only used in one place?

1. It allows versioning of blocks of functionality.
2. It allows re-use/sharing of blocks of functionality between other applications.
3. It provides clearer separation between blocks of functionality.

#### In Angular, specifically

In Angular, too, there's some merit to the idea that not all of your application's functionality needs to be in the same Single Page Application. For instance, not every user of your application might need to load user management code when they're loading the main app. So you could separate that out into a different SPA. But that new SPA might need to share API access code or UI elements, so those things could be encapsulated in Modules.

Likewise, UI elements (directives) are things that could be highly sharable between completely different applications throughout an organization. So those things could be in their own module(s), for just that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

There are many circumstances where organizing and/or breaking the typical angular module into separate modules makes perfect sense; it makes the app easier to maintain, and it makes the app code more accessible and more easily *distributed*.

For instance, if you look at the approach taken [here](https://github.com/trochette/Angular-Design-Patterns-Best-Practices), you can get a better picture of how an angular application can be written and organized more prototypally, with controllers deriving from basecontroller and so forth.

As to why you would break every angular provider type into its own module, I cannot say. It doesn't seem to favor many principles of good design, nor does organizing modules per-provider-type offer much benefit to the app or the developer. It kinda seems like one of those silly things that everyone sees in some answer on SO, then catches on, and begins to crop up in blog posts everywhere (not unlike the imaginary `useXDomain` flag on `$http`).

Advocating it, the best argument I can think of is - it could give you a per-provider-type testing orthogonality.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using the module approach splitting into modules by feature but I am starting to be convinced that there is not much real benefit to it. But read on. First, let's review whats out there...

Miško Hevery discusses it here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&t=34m19s

Then there is the post by Naomi Black:

http://blog.angularjs.org/2014/02/an-angularjs-style-guide-and-best.html

Which references these documents:

https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/angularjs-google-style.html
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub

Also the latest version of angular documentation states:

> ... we recommend that you break your application to multiple modules
>   like this:
>
> - A module for each feature
> - A module for each reusable component (especially directives and filters)
> - And an application level module which depends on the above modules and contains any initialization code.

So although the latest documentation recommends a module for each feature it is unclear what the benefit of that is especially considering Miško talk. And the docs referenced above only say that modules can be used where appropriate. Not must, not should. Sort of can be. If you want to. Unless of course you're developing an independent reusable component then yeah it makes perfect sense.

It can be noted that using modules allows to explicitly state dependencies between chunks of your application but it is also unclear how that specifically complements or improves what is already done with regular DI.

Also we have to clearly separate code organization and angular modules. These are not really directly related. You can neatly organize your code into subdirectories and use a single angular module or a couple modules where appropriate. This is unlike Java where it's required to keep directory structure in sync with packages. Then again it might be comparing apples to oranges. Now whether angular modules facilitate better code organization is another topic and more a question of taste maybe? (personally I like the idea of module per feature and being more explicit).

Hold on though, because there is also the issue of future angular features like lazy loading. According to Miško the module per feature approach should work well with that and it is recommended in the documentation now so the most conservative approach might be to stick with that.

**Summary**

At the present time the benefits are unclear but it is recommended and possibly will be compatible with future functionality so probably it's best to follow current recommendation of module per feature.

*Do not* split by type as shown in question code sample. That is a definite.

Answer (score 0):

Organization for the sake of organization? Who knows! This does tend to sometimes happen when the method used for concatenating everything together (grunt, ASP.NET bundles, etc.) doesn't do well with ordering, so everything turns into a module because the module declaration (with the dependencies) must be loaded by the browser before anything that adds on to the module.

This kind of a division seems especially silly to me, between an app's Controllers, Services, and Directives, because all of those things are going to be strongly coupled to each other anyway. I believe it's unfortunate that the [Angular Seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) project seems to promote this.

For a different alternative, take a look at the organization structure behind the [ng-boilerplate project](https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp), which organizes things into feature directories, so that your directory structure is loosely based on your routes, and the controller, template, and tests for any particular feature are all grouped together.

Answer (score 0):

Every developer can suggest his way to make a good architecture for AngularJs modules.But sometimes there are some problems/conflicts with architecture and you don't know how to solve.For example you have created "moduleA" and "moduleB" and in "moduleA" you need some functions which has already defined in "moduleB".With the same way "moduleB" depends on "moduleA".But here is a circular DI.To solve a problem like this,you have to create your modules not by "Entity" logical.You have to create your modules with "Functional" logical.If you need more information here is a cool and correct snippet about it.

http://www.w3docs.com/snippets/angularjs/angularjs-modules-good-architecture.html

Answer (score -3):

Angular Modules are good for nothing...so far. Except for loading 3rd-party angular code into your app and mocking during testing. Other than that, there is no reason to use more than one module in your app. -- At least that is true for Angular 1.2.

In 1.3 beta, the documentation says ...

- A module for each feature
- A module for each reusable component (especially directives and
  filters)
- And an application level module which depends on the above modules
  and contains any initialization code.

The above is a suggestion. Tailor it to your needs.

Comment: -1 :: code organization is something modules are good for. Period.

Comment: Really? The documentation is going to tell me "Angular Modules are good for nothing...so far. Except for loading 3rd-party angular code into your app and mocking during testing"? Also - how can something be good for nothing EXCEPT something that it is good for?

Comment: That's not angular documentation; however, [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#recommended-setup) is. "While the example above is simple, it will not scale to large applications. Instead we recommend that you break your application to multiple modules like this:

A module for each feature
A module for each reusable component (especially directives and filters)
And an application level module which depends on the above modules and contains any initialization code."

Comment: So now you're quoting from the 1.3beta docs that I explicitly referred .  Good job.

Comment: Would you prefer this [v1.2.0-rc.3](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/docs/guide/module)? See "Recommended Setup"

Comment: Again, 1.3 doc -- which goes on to say "The above is a suggestion. Tailor it to your needs."

Comment: Sure looks like a 1.2.0 rc to me. And you're exactly right. It says "tailor it to your needs". If you don't have need of more than one module, or haven't used angular enough to see any reason for more than one module, you prob shouldn't use more than one module. Keep it simple.

Comment: This answer is horribly wrong. Angular modules are akin to jars in Java or assemblies in .NET. If you have a large application, organizing your code into modules is a must.

Comment: This answer could use some clarification but it is not as wrong as it would seem at first. Here is the original source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&t=34m19s